# Show that $\limsup_{n\to \infty }x_n$ is the biggest limit point of the sequence $(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ a bounded sequence and $E$ the set of the limits point of the sequence $(x_n)$.

I want to show that $$\sup E=\limsup_{n\to \infty }x_n.$$
I have shown that $\limsup_{n\to\infty }x_n\in E$, and thus $\limsup_{n\to\infty }x_n\leq \sup E$. But I can't show the reverse inequality. Any idea ?

Comment: Have another look at the definition of the limsup. Maybe translate it into some statements about epsilons and elements of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

I denote $$\ell:=\sup E\quad \text{and}\quad \alpha =\limsup_{n\to \infty }x_n.$$

Since $\ell$ is an adherent point of $E$, there is a sequence $(\ell_i)_i$ of $E$ that converge to $\ell$. By definition of $E$, for all $\ell_i$ there is a subsequence $(x_{i_k})_k$ that converge to $\ell_i$. Let $$y_{i_j}=\sup\{x_{i_j},x_{i_j+1},x_{i_j+2},...\}.$$
Then, $y_{i_j}\geq x_{i_j}$ for all $j$, and thus,
$$\ell=\lim_{j\to \infty }y_{i_j}\geq \lim_{j\to \infty }x_{i_j}=\ell_i.$$
Letting $i\to \infty $, we get the result.

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand why $\lim_{j\to\infty }y_{i_j}=\ell$ neither why you defined this sequence. Where does it come from.

Comment: I set $y_n:=\sup_{k\geq n}x_k$. Then, $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }x_n:=\lim_{n\to \infty }y_n.$$

Comment: sup E is not always a limit point of E. For example, sup$\{ a\} = a$ is not a limit point of $\{ a\}$.

Comment: @Black: Yes, thank you. Your remark is indeed correct. I should have said adherent point (in 2016 my english was not so good :-) ).